# Flowpayer jQuerytools Scrollable not working in Opera Mini

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, flowplayer, scrollable, opera-mini

The transitions are not working and alse scrolling on smartphones doesnt work too and it seems the whole script isnt working properly in opera mini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera Mini does not really do client side javascript in their browser.
The pages you see in Opera Mini is a reformatted/shrinked version of the original page that you are accustomed to working with in desktop browsers.

Also, smartphone's browsers might not support that specific library you are using.  You might want to have a look at [jquerymobile.com](http://jquerymobile.com)

Comment: well, after searching some hours i also found this everywhere so the client has to live with that. also they all support jquery and jquery tools =)

Comment: Opera Mobile on the other hand is the full implementation of a browser with clientside stuff too.